# Text to Text classification

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I am new comer to the field of data science and have been struggling with a simple classification problem. It seems to be generic enough and I have a suspicion that there must be a better way to frame/model this problem. I would appreciate any help.

**Background**

- In our system, we have millions of tickets (similar to JIRA tickets) where each ticket has attributes like `title`, `description`, `tags` etc.
- A user can create a dashboard and add any number of these tickets to their dashboards. Each dashboard has a `title` and `description`.
- Currently there are ~100k tickets in ~3k dashboards.

**Problem Statement**

- Given a new ticket, I want to suggest which dashboards can it be added to.
- Given a new dashboard, I want to suggest which tickets can be added to it.

**My Attempts**

- In my first attempt, I tried to use a [Multi-Class Text Classification with Doc2Vec & Logistic Regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4).

  - Basically, I created vectors from ticket titles (using Doc2Vec) and then ran a logistic regression with these vectors as input and dashboard titles as labels.
  - However following this approach I only got to 2-3% accuracy.
  - I *think* that is because logistic regression with ~3k labels is not a good choice.
- In my second attempt, I created 2 vectors (using Doc2Vec) for ticket title and dashboard title and trained a neural network with ticket title vector as input and dashboard title vector as output.

  - As before, I only achieved 2% accuracy with this approach.

**Question**

- I would like to know from experts, if I am on the right track here with these approaches? If so, should I continue tweaking my model to improve the accuracy?
- Or am I on a completely incorrect track? If so, are there better approaches to model such a classification problem? I am a bit lost and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I think that is because logistic regression with ~3k labels is not a good choice

you are right but I rephrase it a bit better:

In general, **Classification** with ~3k labels is not a good choice!

You basically have a Search/Recommendation problem. Given your input, you find the best fitting ticket/dashboard and assign it. It is a very interesting ML project actually!

I give a confident starter. If it did not work, please come back with results and I update the answer:

### If you want to go Unsupervised

**Query-Document Matching**

1. Use a simple TF-IDF to vectorise your text
2. Apply a dimensionality reduction to reduce high-dimensionality sparse vectors to low-dimensionality dense vectors. If you use matrix factorisations for this, you are basically doing famous classic [LSA](https://medium.com/acing-ai/what-is-latent-semantic-analysis-lsa-4d3e2d18417a)
3. In that vector space, you find the closest label to your query and assign it to the query

**Topic Modeling**

1. Apply a simple [LDA](https://python-bloggers.com/2021/01/lda-topic-modelling-with-gensim/) to model topics for the corpus
2. Given a query, find the best matching topic of that query and assign the query to that topic (cluster)
3. Please note that LDA finds intrinsic topics. So if your labels are different than topics that it finds, you need to rely on labels and ignore this solution

### A little bit more Supervised##

1. Create a dataset from your corpus (or maybe you already have it) in which sentence pairs (titles, descriptions, etc.) which belong to same topic/label have label $1$, and sentence pairs which belong to different topics/classes/labels have label $-1$ and sentence pairs with *neutral* relation have the label $0$. I put an example as PS at the end.
2. Feed this data to [S-Bert](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html) to fine-tune the pre-trained model
3. [Read this, learn it and use it](https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/retrieve_rerank/README.html) for finding most similar ticket/dashboard to the query

PS: How data for S-Bert looks like (I just made up some dummy examples! hope you get the idea)

```
sentence1: He is a man
sentence2: He is male
label: 1

sentence1: programming is hard
sentence2: Maradona was a magician
label: -1

sentence1: don't know what to write here
sentence2: never mind, I think you got what I mean
label: 0
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kasra. Really grateful for your insight. I went with your first suggestion - Query-Document Matching as it seemed the most suited for my problem. I am using TF-IDF for vectorisation & for finding the closest items I am using cosine similarity. I am seeing a 70% accuracy.
But once I do dimensionality reduction (by using SVD) the accuracy drops to 50% or so. Wondering if that's expected?

Comment: sometimes yes ... make a for loop and increase the number of dimensions gradually. Choose the minimum number of dimensions that gives you enough information. Remember that reducing dimensionality means loosing information anyways, so it is expected. Plz consider accept/upvote in case it helped :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer ✅ (Can't upvote as I don't have enough credits).